# How can we identify whether the winform control is accessing by the main thread or the worker thread, to write the InvokeRequired functionality?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am getting the below exception when i run my windows forms application

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cross-thread operation not valid:
> Control 'MSPerformanceLabel' accessed from a thread other than the
> thread it was created on.'

I understood from the exception and also from the thread safe documentation is, when the thread that is not creating the control (Worker Thread) and is trying to modify the control that time we get this exception.

But How can we identify whether the control is accessing by the main thread or the worker thread, so that I can use the InvokeRequired functionality?

Because in my case I am using the control MSPerformanceLabel in my C# project file TestForm.cs and passing through the below line :

`MSPerformanceLabel.BackColor = Color.Transparent;`

Here I didn't get any error for the control "MSPerformanceLabel"

Then at the below line i am getting an exception:

`MSPerformanceLabel.Enabled = false;`

So, Based on the exception I added the InvokeRequired functionality:

Below is the code snippet:

```
MSPerformanceLabel.BackColor = Color.Transparent;

if (MSPerformanceLabel.InvokeRequired)
            {
                UpdateUIOnStateChanged updateObj = new UpdateUIOnStateChanged(MSPerformanceLabel.Enabled = false);


                MSPerformanceLabel.Invoke(updateObj);
            }
            else
            {
                MSPerformanceLabel.Enabled = false;
            }
```

MSPerformanceLabel is declared in TestForm.Designer.cs file like as shown below:

private System.Windows.Forms.Label MSPerformanceLabel;

And the delegate is declared in TestForm.cs file like as shown below:

internal delegate void UpdateUIOnStateChanged();

But even in the InvokeRequired functionality, it is showing error at the parameter i passed to the function "UpdateUIOnStateChanged".

The error is

> "Method name expected"

So how to pass `MSPerformanceLabel.Enabled = false;` into the function.

I am a beginner for C# and Windows forms application . Please help me to resolve the issue.

**Below is my Updated code:**

```
 private void SetMSPerformanceLabel()
    {
      MSPerformanceLabel.Enabled = false;
    }

    MSPerformanceLabel.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        
        if (MSPerformanceLabel.InvokeRequired)
                    {
                        UpdateUIOnStateChanged updateObj = new 
                      UpdateUIOnStateChanged(this.SetMSPerformanceLabel);        
        
                        MSPerformanceLabel.Invoke(updateObj);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.SetMSPerformanceLabel();
                    }
                   }
```

Comment: `var updateObj = new UpdateUIOnStateChanged(() => this.Enabled = false);`

Comment: In addition to Reza: `MSPerformanceLabel.BackColor = Color.Transparent;` also needs to be done on UI Thread.

Comment: The BackColor property is somewhat special, Winforms can implement it with code that isn't fundamentally thread-unsafe.  Underlying call is Control.Invalidate().  That however does not mean it is actually safe, it just won't blow up badly in a way that makes your program hang or keel over.  The error check is only a heuristic, it cannot be 100% bullet-proof.  If it could be then you wouldn't have to write code like this.  Just keep in mind that you must never use InvokeRequired, that means you have no idea on which thread your code runs and that is the worst way to write threaded code.

Answer (score 0):

Compiler Error [CS0149](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/misc/cs0149) '*Method name expected* ' says '*When creating a delegate, specify a method.*'

As an option, using an [`Action`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.action?view=netframework-4.7.2) delegate, you can simplify the code this way:

```
Action action = () => {/* UI Operations */};
if (this.InvokeRequired)
    this.Invoke(action);
else
    action.Invoke();
```

Comment: Hi, I updated my code in the original post by adding the Set function. And inside that function, i am setting MSPerformanceLabel.Enabled = false; Can I write it like this?

Comment: While this post shows you how easily you can fix the compiler error, I agree with Hans. Don't ignore his comment, specially this part: *Just keep in mind that you must never use InvokeRequired, that means you have no idea on which thread your code runs and that is the worst way to write threaded code.*